# PhpStorm How to hit AJAX breakpoint

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpstorm

In one .js file I have

```
function btnClick(){

// breakpoint can hit here
    $.post('/post.php',{
        msg:$('#message').text('')
        },
        function(data){
        ... // not reached
        });
}
```

And I have some code in `post.php`

```
<?php

$trimmed=trim($_POST['msg']); // added breakpoint but not hit
...
echo 'something';
```

PHP breakpoints and JS breakpoints all hit normally except this in AJAX call from `jQuery.post()`.

When btnClick is run, the breakpoint at `$.post` is hit, then I continue and nothing happened, breakpoints in `post.php` are all not hit

How to configure this?

Comment: you need to have the function called as `...success:function()`, you are not specifying what your function is, and it will be considered an object member but will not be called on ajax success

Comment: @Ma'mounothman  --- I am using the function    jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )      and the 3rd parameter is the 'success' function.   https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: my bad I don't know why I thought you are doing $.ajax.

Comment: How do you debug PHP? If you use Zero config approach (by using "phone handle" icon + Xdebug extension for your browser (it sets the Xdebug cookie that acts as "Debug me flag) .. then Xdebug should see it and trigger debug session. That's, of course, if the same domain & port is used. If not -- you will either need to configure Xdebug to attempt to debug *every single request* or pass Xdebug flag to your URL in your `$.post('/post.php'` line. See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html and https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Can you see the request to `post.php' in the browser network panel?